# jQuery load gzipped script

Tags: jquery, node.js, gzip

I'm trying to load and execute a gzipped script!

The script load.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#ls_text").text("loaded!");
});
```

Gzipped with 7zip to load.js.gz.

My node.js express code for serving the file:

```
app.get('/load.js', function(req, res, next) {
  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');

  var filepath = path.join(__dirname, '/public/load.js.gz');
  var readstream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);

  readStream.pipe(res);

  res.end();
});
```

My jQuery client code for getting the script:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/load.js',
        dataType: "script",
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            alert("loaded");
        }
});
```

In the Browser-Console I'm getting the error "ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED".

I don't want to let express gzip the script at runtime!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pipe to `res`, don't call `res.end()`:

```
app.get('/load.js', function(req, res, next) {
  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');

  var filepath   = path.join(__dirname, '/public/load.js.gz');
  var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);

  readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that file is actually gzipped? I believe that 7zip supports multiple formats.

Comment: I choosed "gzip" as "Archive Format" in the "Add to Archive"-Dialog.

Comment: That sounds right. Have you tried opening the URL directly (instead of using `$.ajax()`)? And I assume that you're still getting the `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` error (and not something else)?

Comment: @Kian here's what I tested with, this works just fine for me in Chrome: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/e1eed50ad706dc0cbf7ae75164e27760

Comment: Got it ("fileStream" not "filestream"). Such a simple error. It work's now!